# I cant add new data to DataGrid

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, datagrid, inotifypropertychanged

I have been searching issues like this and making a lot of changes in my code but I can't solve it.

I have created a DataGrid:

```
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding VarDt}"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding Id}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

The list of the class that Im using is in the Main model.

```
    private List<ObjectVariable> _varDt;
    public List<ObjectVariable> VarDt
    {
        get { return _varDt; }
        set 
        { 
            _varDt = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("VarDt");
        }
    }
```

When I add the data for the first time it works and I can see the values in my DataGrid:

```
        public MainViewModel()
        {
        VarDt = new List<ObjectVariable>()
        {
            new ObjectVariable { Id="9846849", Name="Val1" },
            new ObjectVariable { Id="fregreg", Name="Val2" },
            new ObjectVariable { Id="cd6s8s6", Name="Val3" }
        }; [...]
```

But when I add new items when i execute a command (when i tree item is double clicked), the DataGrid doen's update.
(code where I add the new item that it doens't work):

```
    private ICommand _selectItemCommand;
    public ICommand selectItemCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectItemCommand ?? (_selectItemCommand = new RelayCommand(param => this.LoadContent(param)));
        }
    }

    private void LoadContent(object selectedMenuItem)
    {
        // NEW ITEM THAT IS NOT ADDED WHY???
        VarDt.Add(new ObjectVariable { Id = "cw61851cw", Name = "ValPost" });          
    }
```

I dont know if I am not raising the PropertyChanged event correctly and how I can do it.

Someone can tell me how can I add data correctly to my DataGrid.

Thanks!

**Edit 1: Still not working with observable collection**

Declaration:

```
        private ObservableCollection<ObjectVariable> _varDt;
    public ObservableCollection<ObjectVariable> VarDt
    {
        get { return _varDt; }
        set 
        { 
            _varDt = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("VarDt");
        }
    }
```

Public MainViewModel():

```
            VarDt = new ObservableCollection<ObjectVariable>()
        {
            new ObjectVariable { Id="9846849", Name="ValuesAtStart1" },
            new ObjectVariable { Id="fregreg", Name="ValuesAtStart2" },
            new ObjectVariable { Id="cd6s8s6", Name="ValuesAtStart3" }
        };
```

Command:

```
        private void LoadContent(object selectedMenuItem)
    {

            // NEW ITEM THAT IS NOT ADDED WHY???
            VarDt.Add(new ObjectVariable { Id = "cw61851cw", Name = "ValueInsideCommand" });
    }
```

Result (data from command not added):

[Value inside command not added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfbzx.png)

**Edit 2: Problem found but I dont have the solution**

The DataGrid where I have the problem is inside another View that I manage with another class and a ContentControl:

Actually I have:

- MainViewModel and the MainView.
- VariablesViewModel and VariablesView that i put inside the ContentControl.
  The VariablesViewModel is empty, I only use it to show the VariablesView.

When I execute a command, I show the VariablesView in the ContentControl:

```
        private void LoadContent(object selectedMenuItem)
    {
        TreeItemModel ItemSelected = (TreeItemModel)selectedMenuItem;

        if (ItemSelected.Name == "Object variables")
        {
            // Current view is VariablesView
            CurrentView = VariableVM;

            // NEW ITEM THAT IS NOT ADDED WHY???
            VarDt.Add(new ObjectVariable { Id = "cw61851cw", Name = "ValueInsideCommand" });

        }
            
        else CurrentView = "";
    }
```

I realized that the DataGrid inside the VariablesView that I show in the ContentControl doesn't update the values, but if I put the same DataGrid in the Main View, the values are updated.

Maybe the problem is that "VarDt" is in the MainViewModel, not in VariablesViewModel, but I can show some data, (only the new values are not showed)

Test code:

```
                [...]
            <ContentControl Grid.Column="1"
                            Margin="10"
                            Content="{Binding CurrentView}"/>

            <DataGrid Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" ItemsSource="{Binding VarDt}"  AutoGenerateColumns="True" />
            [...]
```

Result of test Code:
[DataBinding result using ContentControl os DataGrid in MainView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFKEa.png)

**Edit 3: Full context**

Variables view:

```
<UserControl x:Class="AOE.MVVM.View.VariablesView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:AOE.MVVM.ViewModel"  
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AOE.MVVM.View"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
<!--Asignación del archivo .cs a esta view-->
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <viewmodel:MainViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions >
        <RowDefinition Height="30*" MaxHeight="70"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="100*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="10*" MaxHeight="30"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
        <Image Source="/Media/Variables.png"
               Height="50"
               Width="50"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Variables"
                   FontFamily="Verdana"
                   Foreground="#007BC0"/>

    </StackPanel>
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding VarDt}"  AutoGenerateColumns="True" >

    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

VariablesViewModel:
Empty class.

AppXaml:

```
<Application x:Class="AOE.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AOE"
         xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:AOE.MVVM.ViewModel"
         xmlns:view="clr-namespace:AOE.MVVM.View"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:VariablesViewModel}">
        <view:VariablesView/>
    </DataTemplate>

</Application.Resources>
```

MainViewModel:

```
namespace AOE.MVVM.ViewModel
{
class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
{

    public ObservableCollection<ObjectVariable> VarDt { get; set; }

    //public TreeItemModel ItemSelected { get; set; }

    private ICommand _selectItemCommand;
    public ICommand selectItemCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectItemCommand ?? (_selectItemCommand = new RelayCommand(param => this.LoadContent(param)));
        }
    }

    private void LoadContent(object selectedMenuItem)
    {

        // Current view is VariablesView
        CurrentView = VariableVM;

        // NEW ITEM THAT IS NOT ADDED WHY???
        VarDt.Add(new ObjectVariable { Id = "cw61851cw", Name = "ValueInsideCommand" });

    }

    public VariablesViewModel VariableVM { get; set; }

    private object _currentView;

    public object CurrentView
    {
        get { return _currentView; }
        set
        {
            _currentView = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentView");
        }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {

        MainTree.Add(MainObject);

        VarDt = new ObservableCollection<ObjectVariable>()
        {
            new ObjectVariable { Id="9846849", Name="ValuesAtStart1" },
            new ObjectVariable { Id="fregreg", Name="ValuesAtStart2" },
            new ObjectVariable { Id="cd6s8s6", Name="ValuesAtStart3" }
        };

        VariableVM = new VariablesViewModel();

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Use an observablecollection and not a list.

Comment: The new item is added, but the DataGrid does not notice that the collection has changed. Either change the VarDt property to raise the PropertyChanged event (not recommended) or better use the ObservableCollection, which raises the CollectionChanged event to notify the ItemsControl (DataGrid) about the changes.

Comment: Read the remarks to learn more: [INotifyCollectionChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged?view=net-6.0#remarks)

Comment: [Binding to collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/?view=netdesktop-6.0#binding-to-collections)

Comment: Hello, I have already tried but still not working using ObservableCollection<T> instead of List<T>. Any other ideas?

Comment: It's not clear from your posted code where your error is.It should work in the first place. Make sure that you are only using a single instance of MainViewModel (maybe you are changing the collection on an instance different than the one in the DataContext. Please post a minimum viable example that reproduces the behavior if you need more help.

Comment: Hello @BionicCode, I have found the problem but I don't know how to solve it. I will post it with Edit 2 (Thnkas for your help)

Comment: 1) This means the DataGrid is not bound to the MainViewModel like your posted code suggests? It is bound to the VariablesViewModel? 2) How is it implemented, does it defines another VarDt property? 3) And if so, why does the MainViewModel has the same property (although it seems it is not required)? 4) Is the VariablesView loaded using a DataTemplate? It would really help if you show more context instead of lose snippets. Otherwise it is impossible to know how your classes relate to each other.

Comment: @BionicCode I have just added the full context of the problem.

Comment: This is how your question should have looked like from the beginning. hank you, now it seems to make sense: VariablesView defines MainViewModel as its DataContext in XAML. That's why the DataGrid show initial values. Then after loading is completed the DataContext gets overridden by the DataContext of the DataTemplate, which is the empty VariablesViewModel. To fix this I need to know why the VarDt property is in the MainViewModel and not in the VariablesViewModel. Does it make sense to move it completely to the VariablesViewModel?

Comment: And who is oinvoking the selectItemCommand? Can't find it in the VariablesView.

Comment: @BionicCode, Sorry, I have removed part of the code to make it simple, but if it helps, I can copy the full MainViewModel and MainView. The Main concept is that I have a TreeView generated when I execute a Command and I get a Big class with a lot of data inside. Once the data is generated, when I select a item inside the TreeView, the ContentControl should show The VariablesView with the DataGrid. The "VarDt" property should be filled when I load the Main TreeView with the data of the BigClass from MainViewModel.Maybe, Should I pass the data of "VarDt" from that BigClass to VariablesViewModel?

Comment: Do you want VariablesView to be reusable or is it used only in this particular context?

Comment: @BionicCode Only used in this particular context to show the View with the DataGrid, In the future I will create more Views when I select others TreevIewITems.

Comment: My original explanation is not entirely correct. You are creating the MainViewModel twice, this part is correct. Not correct is the part where the VariablesView instance of the MainViewModel gets overridden by the DataTemplate. The problem is simply that you are operating on two different instances of the MainViewModel. I have posted an answer to show possible fixes.

Comment: @BionicCode, Understood the issue. Thanks very much for your time and your knowledge!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`VariablesView` defines `MainViewModel` as its `DataContext` explicitly in XAML. That's why the `DataGrid` shows initial values: the values from the `MainViewModel` constructor. Since this is a new instance, changing the values of one instance does not change the values of the second instance.

Two simple solutions to fix this issue.
One solution can be to bind the `DataContext` of the `VariablesView` to the original `MainViewModel` instance.
You can define a `RelativeSource` to lookup the parent `ContentControl` and uses its `DataContext` as source for the `DataContext` binding:

**VariablesView.xaml**

```xml
<UserControl DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentControl}, Path=DataContext}">
  ...
</UserControl>
```

The second and recommended solution is to use the natural `DataContext`, that is inherited from the `DataTemplate`.

The consequence is that `VariablesViewModel` can't be empty. If `MainViewModel` and `VariablesViewModel` share data like the `VarDt` property, then don't duplicate those properties. Rather bind the controls that depend on this shared properties explicitly to the `DataContext` of the `ContentControl` (MainViewModel). Other non-shared data that relates to `VariablesView` must be moved to the `VariablesViewModel`.

The following example assumes that `VariablesView` is not a reused control. Not, if reusability does matter, all internal bindings *must* reference the inherited `DataContext`. This means `Binding.RelativeSource` to lookup a source outside the UserControl must be avoided.

**VariablesView.xaml**

```xml
<!-- DataContext is inherited from the DataTemplate and is the VariablesViewModel -->
<UserControl>

  <!-- Bind explicitly to the shared data located in MainViewModel -->
  <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentControl}, Path=DataContext}" />
</UserControl>
```